# Simulating stream `error` event for tests

Tags: node.js, stream, jasmine, jasmine-node, istanbul

I'm using the latest [istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) + [jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) to write all my test scripts.

In a few places I have a Readable stream that may emit `error` event, and I have no idea how to simulate such event in a test environment, to provide code coverage.

Can anybody suggest an idea of how to approach this, please?

Comment: Why not just emit an error event on the stream?: `stream.emit('error', new Error('OOPS'));`

Comment: @mscdex, why not publish it as an answer? :)

Comment: @mscdex, I have tried it, and it worked. Thank you! Do you want to publish it as an answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should just be as simple as emitting an error directly on the object:

```
stream.emit('error', new Error('OOPS'));
```